# How to select <input> that has no "type" with CSS

Tags: css, html

I here have 3 `<input>`s in my HTML:

```html
Name: <input><br>
Age: <input type="number"><br>
Site: <input type="url">
```

And I can select the bottom two with these CSS:

```css
input[type="number"]{
    color: gray;
}
input[type="url"]{
    color: blue;
}
```

But I don't know how to select the first one that has no type.
I tried:

```css
input{
    color: red;
}
```

But it will change the other two as well.

```css
input[type=""]{
    color: red;
}
```

This is still not working.
Any idea?

Comment: your code work check this http://jsfiddle.net/Wh42e/

Comment: Why not set `type` to `text`?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The selector `input[type=""]` will look for an input that has the attribute `type` which is set to empty. Try using this:

```
input:not([type]) { }
```

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6WpCC/)

Comment: Wow, I had never thought you can do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Another approach could be to use **CSS Specificity**, and apply a general style to all input elements, then apply more specific styles to inputs with `type` attribute. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for cross-browser compatibility is probably just defining what you want and then re-defining it for every other type of input. ie:

```
input {
    color: red;
}
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"],
...
input[type="input"] {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dosen't​ work​ in​ IE6​

```
input[type="text"]:first-child
```

OR​

```
#form input[type="text"]:first-child
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add an id or class attribute onto the input you would like to target. So for example:

```
Name: <input id="name-input">
```

Then in your css:

```
#name-input
{
   color: red
}
```