# Why type="text" is lost in input when uploading to a hosting, nuxtjs?

Tags: nuxt.js

I currently have the following input

```
 <div class="md-form">
      <input
       class="form-control"
       id="name"
       type="text"
       name="name"
       required="required"
      />
      <label for="name">Name*</label>
     </div>
```

when working with `npm run dev`, when checking to inspect the element, the input is seen without problem, then I perform an `npm run generate` and `npm run start` and without problems with the input.
At the time of uploading it to the hosting, the input no longer has `type="text"` as I show it below:

[image]

Having no `type="text"` loses the style.

Comment: Did you try removing the / at the end of your input declaration? HTML 5 does not require the end / anymore: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text

Answer (score 1):

The `nuxt generate` use the [html-minifier](https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier) lib to minify the *.vue pages.

It's a default optimization from Nuxt call `removeRedundantAttributes`.

The attribute `type=text` is remove because it's already the default value of type in HTML5, so it's like redundant.

You can force to disable the minify of html:
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#html-minify (**but i don't recommend doing that**)

```js
// nuxt.config.js

{
  html: {
    minify: {
      removeRedundantAttributes: true
    }
  }
}
```

So, if you keep the original minify, you have to use another css rule (eg. without type or with a custom class)

Comment: I added it, but it didn't work at the time of uploading it to the hosting, only local in dev or production mode if it works without problems

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else lands here, as an alternate approach, try using a selector without a specified input type.

`input:not([type])`

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8222665/1634817